# MySQL Complex Join - 4 Tables with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I need help creating a complex SQL query that is a little beyond my rather basic knowledge... I would greatly appreciate anyone's help!

See below for database structure. The bold row represents the tables; below are the relevant fields for each table.

I included below the desired output fields as well as conditions for the query.

### **Database Structure**

**custom_fields_data...........sales_listings.........sales.........listings**

........owner_id.........   .................listing_id.......... buyer_id...........id

.........field_id...............................sale_id..................id.............name

..........value..............................created_at

### **Database relationships:**

**custom_fields_data**.owner_id = **sales_listings**.listing_id = **listings**.id

**sales_listings**.sale_id = **sales**.id

### **Conditions:**

**custom_fields**_data.field_id = 4
**sales**.buyer_id = 12, 20, 21 or 30

### **Desired output:**

**listings**.id
**listings**.name
**custom_fields_data**.value
**sales_listings**.created_at

Thank you, I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: You should add the piece of code you have come up for rather than just ask for complete answer.

Comment: I'd be happy to do that but I have absolutely no idea how to even start the query... Joining two tables is a challenge for me, not to mention 4 tables with conditions...

Comment: There is a nice tutorial here - http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/default.asp. Just understand the basics, and you should be able to grasp. Writing SQL will come to you naturally, just practice for sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very straight forward. Break your problem into 3 parts :

1. What columns you want as output
2. What tables you want data from and join conditions
3. What are specific conditions

I see you have already broken the problem, but just haven't attempted to write the query.

I am no expert on MySQL, but in T-SQL, it would look like the following:

```
  SELECT listings.id
      listings.name
      custom_fields_data.value
      sales_listings.created_at    
    FROM custom_fields_data
       INNER JOIN sales_listings ON sales_listings.listing_id = custom_fields_data.owner_id
       INNER JOIN sales ON sales.id = sales_listings.sale_id
       INNER JOIN listings ON listings.id = sales.Id
    WHERE custom_fields_data.field_id = 4 
        AND sales.buyer_id IN (12, 20, 21, 30)
```

In your question, you havent clearly defined the relationship bettween Listing table and other tables. So I have assumed sales.id = listings.id.

Comment: Thank you so much. After seeing your solution, it really is straight forward. I guess I was just intimidated and confused by the apparent complexity.

Comment: I bet you were on the right track of breaking down the problem. Just practice more examples and you should be a pro in no time :)